# Merging 2 arrays into one array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables

I have created 2 arrays and I want to merge the array of objects into one filling up all the columns
For example:

```
var array = [{"first_name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46}, 
  {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26},
  {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":31},
  {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28}, 
  {"first_name":"Samantha", "Last Name":"Williams", "age":32 }];

var array2 = [{"first_namee":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46, "height": "65"}, 
  {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26, "height": "58"}, 
  {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":66, "height": "69"}, 
  {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28, "height": "72"}];
```

I want to merge the 2 arrays of objects into one like the following:

```
var arrayMerge = [{"first_name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46, "height": "65"}, 
  {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26, "height": "58"}, 
  {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":66, "height": "69"}, 
  {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28, "height": "72"}, 
  {"first_name":"Samantha", "Last Name":"Williams", "age":32, "height": ""}];
```

How would I do this for the 2 arrays, I tried concat and merge and it gives me both arrays in one, without having all the columns into one

Comment: By "columns" are you referring to object keys?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant

Comment: It's not a terribly simple operation. You have to decide a few things first. 1. How do you identify an object as unique? The first name? Last? Both? Both and age? etc... 2. Which array is the truth? `array` has fewer values than `array2`, what if `array2` has a different age? Which one should it keep?

Comment: So the goal is merging all the objects keys into one array.since the only different is the height, and one new person if on array 2 with no height, I want to merge them together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, assuming the objects are in the same order in the arrays, you could map over the first one and generate a new object for array element by using `Object.assign()` to merge the two objects together.

Like this:

```
const mergeArraysOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.map((obj1, idx) => Object.assign({}, obj1, arr2[idx]))
```

You can also use the new object spread operator:

```
const mergeArraysOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.map((obj1, idx) => ({ ...obj1, ...arr2[idx] }))
```

Demo with spread operator:

```js
const array = [{"first_name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46}, {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26}, {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":31}, {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28}, {"first_name":"Samantha", "Last Name":"Williams", "age":32 }];
const array2 = [{"first_namee":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46, "height": "65"}, {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26, "height": "58"}, {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":66, "height": "69"}, {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28, "height": "72"}];

const mergeArraysOfObjects = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.map((obj1, idx) => ({ ...obj1, ...arr2[idx] }));
  
console.log(mergeArraysOfObjects(array, array2));
```

Answer (score 1):

A not so flexible option is to use the ES6 spread operator, and after that, you can fill in the differences:

```js
let array = [{"first_name":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46}, {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26}, {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":31}, {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28}, {"first_name":"Samantha", "Last Name":"Williams", "age":32 }];

let array2 = [{"first_namee":"John", "Last Name":"Doe", "age":46, "height": "65"}, {"first_name":"Tim", "Last Name":"Jones", "age":26, "height": "58"}, {"first_name":"Marcus", "Last Name":"Brown", "age":66, "height": "69"}, {"first_name":"Paul", "Last Name":"Daniels", "age":28, "height": "72"}];

let mergedArray = [...array, ...array2]
mergedArray.map(item => {
  if (!item.height) {
    item.height = ""
  }
})

console.log(mergedArray)
```